# jQuery mmenu has little delay on open action

Tags: mmenu

i'm using this very nice plugin on my website for mobile device and i notified that when click to open menu, it takes 1 sec delay.

Also in the demo plugin page mmenu.frebsite.nl (visit from mobile) you should see the same behaviour.

In the code: jquery.mmenu.js ln 74 there is a sort of note about this delay.

Could it be fixed and have a fluid open/close menu? (close action is perfect)

thx for any response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of plugin replied to me, he said that is normal.
Some browser could have this delay.

So i have to change the plugin.